# XSLT Going through array value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="WepNr" select="/*/DbResponse/ResultSet/Row[Cell[@name='ARTNR']=$ArtNr][Cell[@name='WEANR']=$WeaNr]/Cell[@name='WEPNR']"/>
```

It can return multiple values, so in that case it will output something like: `2 21 36` =3 values.

I try to go through them:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$WepNr">
    <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="$WepNr"/></LineNumber>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but it just outputs same value `2 21 36` for three times:

```
<LineNumber>2 21 36</LineNumber>
<LineNumber>2 21 36</LineNumber>
<LineNumber>2 21 36</LineNumber>
```

How can I output 3 times like:

```
<LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
<LineNumber>21</LineNumber>
<LineNumber>36</LineNumber>
```

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're selecting the entire variable again inside the for-each.

You probably want something like (untested):

```
<xsl:for-each select="$WepNr">
    <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="."/></LineNumber>
</xsl:for-each>
```